# Can’t read code on blown capacitor

Tags: inverter, charger, ups

I have a blown capacitor with damaged code (maybe 102?45)it’s from a charging circuit board from an
8zed-2000S-12v-UPS inverter/charger/UPS.240v-15amp charger the markings on the board are NTC1. I can’t find the schematics online. Is it possible to identify this capacitor?[image]

Comment: That's looks like a negative temperature coefficient thermistor (NTC) used for inrush protection, not a capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

It is a negative coefficient thermister (NTC) not a capacitor. The partial code "102" likely means 1000 ohms.

Comment: It might not be a 2 and 1000 ohms for inrush limiting would also not make much sense.

Comment: I haven't indicated a use. PTCs (not NTCs) are used for inrush current limiting. I am confident that the third digit is a 2. @Justme

Comment: NTCs are used for inrush limiting. When it heats up it has lower resistance. PTCs are used too but for different reasons (under a fault condition of continuous high current they go high resistance and don't conduct).